# how to remove dublicate proxies in list?

Tags: regex, list, notepad++, edit

i have a proxy list like this :

> 5.5.5.5:62359
>     4.4.4.4:95684
>     6.6.6.6:65419
>     4.4.4.4:95684
>     7.7.7.7:65487

now i want to convert top list to this :

> 5.5.5.5:62359
>     4.4.4.4:95684
>     6.6.6.6:65419
>     7.7.7.7:65487

--> i want to remove dublicate proxies in list

**are there any website or program or notepad++ regex that do this ?**

Comment: Tool recommendations are off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: You could very easily do that with e.g. `Python` and `set()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the answer [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/duplicatelines.html). But **it will not work without sorting alphabetically.**

Search

```
^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+$
```

Replace

```
\1
```

The find and replace with regex function worked on Notepad++.

[image: notepad++]

But, it doesn't work on visual studio code.

Comment: tnx - but it not working with notepad++

Comment: Sorry, I read the ref it said you must sort alphabetically otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to do it in sublime text. just open the file and eidt -> permute lines -> unique

Comment: tnx - this worked